# What makes the array rotate left without temp?

Tags: c, arrays, rotation

So I am writing a program to move arrays to the right if **positive** and left if **negative**. I am just creating two different functions one to rotate by **X** right if the value were lets say **X** and left **X** if the value was **-X**. So if the value was -4 i could just apply the left function to 4. Basically **rotate_r** makes my array rotate right. I want my **rotate_l** to move my array left. I have no idea how to reverse the effects of rotate_r to make rotate_l go the opposite way.Here is my code. TLDR;Basically I want to make the function with oo,kk move the array left instead of right

```
#include<stdio.h>

void rotate_r(int *array, int size, int r)
{
   int ii, jj;

   for (ii = 1; ii <= r; ii++)
   {
     for (jj = size-1; jj > 0; jj--)
     {
       /* swapping the array[jj] and array[jj-1] elements without
          using temporary variable */
        array[jj-1] = array[jj-1] + array[jj];
        array[jj] = array[jj-1] - array[jj];
        array[jj-1] = array[jj-1] - array[jj];
     }
   }

   return;
}
void rotate_l(int *array, int size, int l)
{
   int oo, kk;

   for (oo = 1; oo <= l; oo++)
   {
     for (kk = size-1; kk > 0; kk--)
     {
       /* swapping the array[jj] and array[jj-1] elements without
          using temporary variable */
        array[kk-1] = array[kk-1] + array[kk];
        array[kk] = array[kk-1] - array[kk];
        array[kk-1] = array[kk-1] - array[kk];
     }
   }

   return;
}


int main()
{
     int a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, oo;

    rotate_l(a, 10, 4);

     printf("After rotating a by 4\n");
     for (oo = 0; oo < 10; oo++)
     {
      printf("%5d", a[oo]);
     }
      printf("\n");

     return 0;
  }
```

Comment: soon you can get various good answer for your question in this link http://www.codechef.com/SEPT14/problems/ROTATION

Comment: This code is actually undefined behavior because of signed integer overflow. If you make `array` unsigned, then it is fine.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you are implying @DoxyLover.Are you saying that function rotation_r would be able to read both positive and negative integers if it is unsigned and move accordingly?

Comment: The whole point of this is to simply rotate the fixed sequence, correct? Ex: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`, rotated right-3 gives `6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5` ?  Or did I totally misunderstand the intent? (left-rotate omitted for brevity).

Comment: @WhozCraig yes that is correct.

Comment: Are you open to an alternate approach, or are you married to this one? (and if this is, indeed, for code chef, you really don't need rotations at all, just a pointer to move around and some math to maintain). But if you want to know how to do this in O(N), I can show you (as I'm sure others can as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rotating to the right, you were starting the inner loop with `jj=size-1` and swapping elements `jj-1` and `jj`. When rotating to the left, start the inner loop with `kk=0` and swap elements `kk` and `kk+1`.

```
void rotate_l(int *array, int size, int l)
{
   int oo, kk;

   for (oo = 1; oo <= l; oo++)
   {
      for (kk = 0; kk < size-1; ++kk)
      {
         /* swapping the array[kk] and array[kk+1] elements without
            using temporary variable */
         array[kk] = array[kk+1] + array[kk];
         array[kk+1] = array[kk] - array[kk+1];
         array[kk] = array[kk] - array[kk+1];
      }
   }

   return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To rotate left, you need to start swapping from the start of the array. So, change your rotate_l() function like this. Look at the inner loop condition.

```
void rotate_l(int *array, int size, int l)
{
   int oo, kk;

   for (oo = 1; oo <= l; oo++)
   {
     for (kk = 1; kk <size; kk++) 
     {
       /* swapping the array[jj] and array[jj-1] elements without
          using temporary variable */
        array[kk-1] = array[kk-1] + array[kk];
        array[kk] = array[kk-1] - array[kk];
        array[kk-1] = array[kk-1] - array[kk];
     }
   }
   return;
}
```

But, I would suggest you use circular array to get the best complexity.
Here is the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)

Answer (score 0):

```
   void rotate_l(int *array, int size, int l)
  { 
     int oo, kk;

     for (oo = 1; oo <= l; oo++)
     {
        for (kk = 0; kk < size-1; ++kk)
        {
          /* swapping the array[kk] and array[kk+1] elements without
             using temporary variable */
             array[kk] = array[kk+1] + array[kk];
             array[kk+1] = array[kk] - array[kk+1];
             array[kk] = array[kk] - array[kk+1];
        }
     }

     return;
  }
```

@R Sahu this was the exact answer i was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In **ruby** its quite simple.

```
 def array_rotate(arr)
    i, j = arr.length - 1, 0
    arr[j],arr[i], i, j = arr[i], arr[j], i - 1, j + 1 while(j<arr.length/2)
    puts "#{arr}"
end
```